# OpenGL static linking error

Tags: opengl, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to set up OpenGL but I keep getting this error in visual studio:

```
c:\freeglut\include\gl\freeglut_std.h(68): fatal error C1189: #error :  Static linking is not supported with this build. Please remove the FREEGLUT_STATIC preprocessor directive, or download the source code from http://freeglut.sf.net/ and build against that.
```

How do I set up OpenGL in Visual Studio to do this? The source I'm using is on the opengl-redbook website ch3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is fairly self explanatory.  The version of the freeglut library that you downloaded is unable to link statically(that is, to be included in the resulting executable).  So you need to either remove the preprocessor directive as it suggests or download a different copy of freeglut that is made for static linking.

Opening the Visual Studio 2012 solution file provided with the download from the free glut website, one of the options to build is debug_static.  Choose this and/or release_static for a release build of your project and it will generate a statically linkable library for you.

Comment: The download for free glut only contains a bin, include, and lib folder that has not visual studio solution. Where can I get this solution file for building?

Comment: http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/freeglut/freeglut-2.8.1.tar.gz?download -> This is for the latest version.  A tar extractor is required the way they package it.  WinRar is popular with those.

Comment: Sorry to continue but then what do I build? If I'm supposed to build freeglut_static vc++ 6 project then that fails right out of the box for visual studio 2012. It gives me a prompt about having to upgrade for compatibility then states the upgrade has failed?

Comment: The path I get is freeglut-2.8.1/VisualStudio/2012/freeglut.sln.

Comment: Under freeglut-2.8.1/VisualStudio/2012/ There is only one project and that is freeglut. There are also a bunch of directories. Is it somewhere down the build directory?

Comment: Reset it up changing the old freeglut include and lib paths to the new freeglut-2.8 lib and include folders and now I'm getting a cannot find freeglut.lib error.

Comment: My first thought on that would be that it is looking for the wrong file name.  Look in the output directory from building freeglut and see if maybe they named it freeglut_static or something to differentiate it from the dynamic freeglut library.

Comment: I found the freeglut lib at this path:C:\freeglut-2.8.1\lib\x86\Debug but now I get the error:cannot open file 'glew_static_vs2010_d.lib'

Comment: Lol wow I think I got it now. I must build AGAIN for glew. Hopefully this will be the end of this.

Comment: Ok, so I got no more glew_static_vs2010 error but now I have a cannot find glew32.lib and rightfully so as there is no glew32.lib after the build. Perhaps you could lend me a hand on what I might have not done here? I built from C:\glew-1.9.0\build\vc10 and included the C:\glew-1.9.0\lib. What else must be done to finally get this running?